# Recover a nil interface through type assertion

Tags: go, types, polymorphism

Consider the following (demo https://go.dev/play/p/VrJx-eEij14)

```
type myError struct {
    err error
}

func (e myError) Error() string { return e.err.Error() }

func main() {
    var (
        err       error = fmt.Errorf("%w", myError{errors.New("I am an error")})
        nilErr    error = nil
        errAny    any   = err
        nilErrAny any   = nilErr
    )

    {
        recErr, ok := errAny.(error)
        fmt.Println(recErr, ok)
    }

    {
        recErr, ok := nilErrAny.(error)
        fmt.Println(recErr, ok)
    }
}
```

It prints

```
I am an error true
<nil> false
```

while I expected it to print

```
I am an error true
<nil> true
```

Trying the same exercice replacing the interface type `error` with `*int` (demo https://go.dev/play/p/NtHVyYO9Hfj)

```
func main() {
    var (
        p       *A  = &A{}
        nilp    *A  = nil
        pAny    any = p
        nilpAny any = nilp
    )

    {
        rec, ok := pAny.(*A)
        fmt.Println(rec, ok)
    }

    {
        rec, ok := nilpAny.(*A)
        fmt.Println(rec, ok)
    }
}
```

does yield to the output I expect

```
&{} true
<nil> true
```

Why can one recover a nil int pointer from an empty interface but not a nil error from an empty interface?

---

FYI, the specific situation I am trying to solve is one, where I am caching errors. The values cached are of type `any`. Some errors cached are `nil`. I care about the difference between a `nil` error and an object that I could unexpectedly not type assert into an error because I would have messed my cache up.

Comment: The assignment `nilErrAny any = nilErr` assigns the value and dynamic type in `nilErr` to `nilErrAny`.  The interface type is not assigned.  The type assertion `nilErrAny.(error)` fails because `nilErrorAny`'s dynamic type (nil in this case) does not satisfy the `error` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, a variable of interface type is an intermediate object that contains a pointer to the actual object and information about the type of that object, and it is possible for the interface value to be "empty", which is represented by the keyword `nil` (though this situation is distinct from a nil pointer). Thus, there are two ways in which a variable of interface type can "be nil": the variable itself can be nil (the intermediate object is empty), or the intermediate object contains a pointer to the actual object is nil. Assigning the literal `nil` to a variable of interface type produces the first situation. You can produce the second situation with e.g. `nilErr error = nil.(*myError)`, or by assigning a nil pointer that is already held in a variable of type `*myError`.

Comment: Not quite. An interface value is a 2 word value (not intrinsically a pointer), containing the dynamic type and value. The dynamic value may be contained within the interface value or it may be a pointer depending on type and size. This is unspecified though, and can and has changed over time.

Comment: @JimB: Rephrased to avoid usage of the word "pointer" for the interface value itself.